# Angular 6: How can I hide header when I click on login?

Tags: angular, ionic3, angular6

I want show and hide header component from login container. When I click on "Angular & Bootstrap" text. It's working but not working from login component. I am currently working in Angular 6. Is there any other way for doing this?

Header Component html

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark mb-5" *ngIf="login">
 <a class="navbar-brand" routerLink="" href="#" (click)="ngToggleheader()">Angular & Bootstrap</a></nav>
```

Header Component ts file

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthGuard } from '../../_guards/';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  login: boolean;
  constructor(public navCtrl: Router, public auth: AuthGuard) {
    this.login = auth.checkLogin();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.login = this.auth.checkLogin();
  }

  ngToggleheader(){
    this.login = (this.login) ? false : true;
  }

  logout() {
    this.login = false;
    localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
    this.navCtrl.navigate(['/login'], {});
  }

}
```

Login page ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { HeaderComponent } from '../ui/header/header.component';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(public navCtrl: Router, public header: HeaderComponent) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  logintry() {
    //localStorage.setItem( 'currentUser' , 'true' );
    this.header.ngToggleheader();
  //  this.navCtrl.navigate(['/home'], {});
  }
}
```

Login html

```html
 <div class="login-container">
  <div class="loginForm">
    <form>
      <div class="hgroup">
        <img src="../../assets/images/logo-login.png" width="150" alt="" />
      </div>

      <br>
      <div class="group">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username">

      </div>
      <div class="group">
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password">
      </div>
      <a (click)="logintry()" class="buttonui">SIGN IN</a>

    </form>

  </div>
</div>
```

Please help.

Comment: @DavidWalschots I removed repeated line please answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add  localStorage.setItem('login',false); 
              login=localStorage.getItem('login');
 in the html file

```
<app-header *ngIf="!login"></app-header>
```

and when the user is logged change  login to true 
localStorage.setItem('select', true);

Comment: Thank you i implement this code in my layout.component and it works. no need to use local storage for that. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can call authservice to check whether the user is logged in or not

```
checkLogin () {
    let user = localStorage.getItem('currentUser');
    if (user !== null) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: But it's not changing value when i call from login component. It's working only if i call this function from header component.

Comment: Post your `checkLogin()`

Comment: And generally login only show when we are logged out of the system in that case we need to `return false`

Comment: checkLogin () {
        if (localStorage.getItem('currentUser')) {
            // logged in so return true
            return true;
        } else {
            this.router.navigate(['/login'], {});
            return false;
        }

    }

Comment: Right now i am not using it.

Comment: use this. if you are assign the value to some vairable then you have to return value not navigate to other page.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have the boolean attribute `login` in you `HeaderComponent` why don't you use it to hide and show the header, like this:

```
<app-header *ngIf="login"></app-header>
```

and the `login` attribute becomes `true` when you successfully login.

Comment: Thank you i implement this code in my layout.component and it works. :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe prepare two separate routes: one only for login page(without header component), another one for content(with header component).

Then implement autoredirect for chosen pages:

```
@Injectable()
export class SecurityGuard implements CanActivate {

constructor(private router: Router, private securityService: SecurityService) {
}

canActivate(route:ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot):boolean {
   if(this.securityService.isAuthenticated()){
      return true
   }else{
      this.router.navigate(['login'])
      return false
   }
 }
}
```